# iOS SDK: pngs don't show up in interface builder

Tags: iphone, ios

I've tried adding images to my XCode project. I've dropped and dragged a couple of pngs into my project, and they are listed in the left pane.

When I open up a XIB in Interface Builder, the images don't show up in the media library.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a corrupted Xcode 4 install. Thanks to those who contributed answers!

Answer (score 0):

While adding the images to your project make sure that you tick the check box for Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)

[image: Check this image]

Also try the PengOne's solution.

Comment: Thanks Adarsh. Bad XCode 4 install... back to 3.2.5!

Comment: XCode 4 is good :) ... First uninstall older versions Xcode and install Xcode 4. Hope the errors will go away. Good luck.

Comment: As far as interface goes, I like Xcode 4. But I gotta ship something. Once that's done, I'm taking your advice and fixing Xcode 4.